# Facebook API: Get Location/Place ID from an event

Tags: facebook, api, events, facebook-graph-api

if I access to an event via the Graph API I only get the name of the location but on the facebook site it is linked to a location with an unique ID. Can I get access to this ID via the API or it is necessary to parse this ID myself.

Best regards
Andy

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the "venue" info is only returned on certain venues.  I'm still trying to determine why some show up and others don't - my initial thought is that it has to be an "official" address or some such.  For example this event has "venue" info:

https://graph.facebook.com/147330072002695

But yours doesn't:

https://graph.facebook.com/216169778395404

Comment: Actually, it looks like the location may have to be a "verified" place on bing.com/maps.  I guess I should have expected as much when Facebbok got in bed with Microsoft....  Grrrrr....

Answer (score 0):

Once you get your event you can search for the place with the lat and long co-ordinates and then pick the location if it is in the list.

Here's an example using the [Branches FB API](http://fbapi.blogspot.com):

```
Dim FB As New SessionInfo("[access_token]")
Dim Req = New Functions.Requests(FB)
Dim EV = Req.GetEvent("331218348435")
'Search the co-ordinates returned
Dim PL = Req.GetCheckInsNearMe(" ", EV.venue.latitude, EV.venue.longitude, 25)
For Each P In PL
    If P.name = ev.location then
        'Location Found
         MyPlaceID = P.id
    end if
Next
```

Comment: thx for your answer, but in this case I don't have latitude and longitude only this connection to that place, but in the graph API it is only shows as a name. My current idea is to parse myself pages like www.facebook.com/event.php?eid=123456789 this seems to works and I get the ID but I don't think this should be the solution, because I don't know how often i can send these Requests.

Comment: if you use the api it will returnt he lat and lng as a part of the object.

Comment: you can always test for it.  The alternative would be to connet to google and get the co-ordinates there then pass those into FB.  Out of curiosity where are you getting a place id because I don't see that in the event object's json response.

Comment: can you update your post with the response that facebook gives to you with the exact call tha tyou made to get it please?

I suspect that the place has to exist in facebook for it to have the information tha tyou are looking for.  Otherwise it might just be test and nothing more.

Comment: i have created an test event for you http://www.facebook.com/event.php?eid=216169778395404 yeah that's the exact problem in the event object's json response there is no place ID, but if you see my link there is a connection to a place with an ID and I try to get this ID but over the API it seems not to work

Comment: When you added the event did you specify an address or did you only put the name of place that the event was at?

Comment: I only put the place there, but this is usual of most of the events. If there is an adress it is no problem for me to get the location, but you see if you visit the event over the Facebook site (not the API) there is an link to that location with the ID. I solved the problem to parse these sites with HttpRequests but as i said that shouldn't be a solution and I don't know if Facebook like such a lot of HttpRequests.

Comment: I linked the place to an existing place (you see it if you visit facebook.com/event.php?eid=216169778395404)

Comment: I did see that but it also appears that it's a place that has a name in common with other places.  It may be that FB soesn't support this at the moment but you could ask tehm to add it to the social graph.  If they can show it on the page then they can put it into the graph.

Comment: do you know where i have to ask to put the feature in the social graph? Will it be a great problem for them? But with my own parser it works for the momenent. I hope in the future they will implement it.

Comment: @middletone A year have passed, but long/lat still isn't supported with FB when creating/updating event: http://developers.connect.facebook.com/bugs/173095916131752/?browse=search_4f46c32fe98dd2136488627

Comment: I don't work for facebook so until they impliment the feature there is nothing that I can do for you.